# Sharepoint portal office documents not opening on browser

Tags: sharepoint, browser, server

this is my first post on the forum. I have been searching all around the web and the forum and I can`t find any solution to the problem, so:

**Context**
I have a Sharepoint 2019 On-Premise server on an intranet without internet conexion. Clients have a licensed office 2016 installed on the computers without internet conexion.

**Issue**
When the users open documents from the portal, they open in the desktop office app. I want them to open in the browser.

**Troubleshooting**
The browser:
The browser used is Edge. The Edge version is 121.0.2277.112 (64bit).
The sharepoint portal is opening on IE Explorer compatibility mode.
The "Open Office files in the browser" setting, on downloads is on.

The Sharepoint portal:
"Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents" is "Open in the browser" (Library Settings > Advanced settings)
The "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" is not active (Site Settings > Site Collection Features).

I have also tried with Firefox and the result is the same.
Is there anything else that I have to do in order to edit documents on the browser that I am missing?
Thanks in advance.